# Движение квадрата снизу вверх (анимация)

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, анимация, рисование

Задумка такая, сделать анимированный фон у формы (залитый градиент на всю форму статичный и квадраты появляющиеся снизу и движущиеся снизу вверх и возможно все это заблюрить не много).

Вопрос такой: чтобы реализовать движение квадратов (белых) их нужно перерисовывать? Это делать в отдельном цикле или уже готовое решение есть?

Например пишем `UpdateEvenet` и все что в функции `paintEvent` перерисовалось.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRadialGradient, QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QBrush, QGradient, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, Qt, QRect

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
 d = 0
 def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()

     self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
     self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

     self.resize(600, 400)


 def paintEvent(self, event):
     painter = QPainter(self)

     radialGrad = QRadialGradient(0.3, 0.7, 0.05)
     radialGrad.setCoordinateMode(QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
     radialGrad.setSpread(QGradient.ReflectSpread)
     radialGrad.setColorAt(0, QColor('#0250c5'))
     radialGrad.setColorAt(1, QColor('#2575fc'))
     painter.setBrush(radialGrad)

     painter.drawRect(self.rect())                                    # +++ rect

     painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))  # white red
     painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, -1))                    # +++
     painter.drawRect(100,  self.height()-12, 1, 1)                 # +++ height
     painter.drawRect(200, self.height()-12+self.d, 2, 2)                    # +++ height
     painter.drawRect(300, self.height()-12, 3, 3)                    # +++ height
     self.d -= 1
     if self.d < -400:
         self.d = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать, но вариант анимации я вам покажу.

Также рекомендую вам познакомиться с `QWidget::update()` - обновляет виджет, если обновления не отключены или виджет не скрыт. 
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class CirclingWidget(QWidget):
    offset = QPoint()
    
    def __init__(self, diameter=1, relative=True, sprite=None, 
            anglesPerSecond=360, clockwise=True, offset=None, alignment=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.relative = relative
        self.clockwise = clockwise
        self.setSprite(sprite, offset or alignment)
        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(startValue=0., endValue=1., 
            duration=360000 / anglesPerSecond, loopCount=-1)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.update)

    def setSprite(self, sprite, arg):
        if isinstance(sprite, str):
            sprite = QPixmap(sprite)
        if isinstance(sprite, QPixmap) and not sprite.isNull():
            self.sprite = sprite
            if isinstance(arg, Qt.AlignmentFlag):
                self.setAlignment(arg)
            else:
                self.setOffset(arg)
        else:
            self.sprite = None
        self.update()

    def setAlignment(self, alignment=None):
        if self.sprite:
            x = y = 0
            if alignment is not None:
                if alignment & Qt.AlignHCenter:
                    x = -self.sprite.width() / 2
                elif alignment & Qt.AlignRight:
                    x = -self.sprite.width()
                if alignment & Qt.AlignVCenter:
                    y = -self.sprite.height() / 2
                elif alignment & Qt.AlignBottom:
                    y = -self.sprite.height()
            self.offset = QPointF(x, y)
        self.update()

    def setOffset(self, offset=None):
        if self.sprite:
            x = y = 0
            if isinstance(offset, int):
                x = y = offset
            elif isinstance(offset, float):
                x = self.sprite.width() * offset
                y = self.sprite.height() * offset
            elif isinstance(offset, (QPoint, QPointF)):
                x = offset.x()
                y = offset.y()
            elif isinstance(offset, (tuple, list)):
                x, y = offset
            self.offset = QPointF(x, y)
        self.update()

    def setAnglesPerSecond(self, ratio):
        self.animation.setDuration(360000 / ratio)

    def setClockwise(self, clockwise=True):
        if self.clockwise != clockwise:
            self.clockwise = clockwise
            self.animation.setCurrentTime(
                self.animation.duration() - self.animation.currentTime())
            self.update()

    def start(self, angle=0):
        self.animation.start()
        # угол считается по часовой стрелке, начиная с 12ч
        start = (angle - 90) / 360 % 1
        self.animation.setCurrentTime(start * self.animation.duration())
        self.update()

    def stop(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter  = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHints(painter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 1, Qt.SolidLine))

        size = self.diameter
        if self.relative:
            size *= min(self.width(), self.height())

        rect = QRectF(0, 0, size, size)
        rect.moveCenter(QRectF(self.rect()).center())
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(rect)   
        painter.drawPath(path)

        if self.sprite:
            pos = self.animation.currentValue()
            if not self.clockwise:
                pos = 1 - pos
            pos = path.pointAtPercent(pos)
            painter.drawPixmap(pos + self.offset, self.sprite)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    d = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.circleWidget = CirclingWidget(.7, sprite='NLO.png',            #  NLO.png
            anglesPerSecond=60, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
            
        self.setCentralWidget(self.circleWidget)
        self.circleWidget.start(90)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        radialGrad = QRadialGradient(0.3, 0.7, 0.05)
        radialGrad.setCoordinateMode(QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
        radialGrad.setSpread(QGradient.ReflectSpread)
        radialGrad.setColorAt(0, QColor('#0250c5'))
        radialGrad.setColorAt(1, QColor('#2575fc'))
        painter.setBrush(radialGrad)

        painter.drawRect(self.rect())                                  

        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))  
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, -1))                 
        painter.drawRect(100,  self.height()-12, 1, 1)               
        painter.drawRect(200, self.height()-12+self.d, 2, 2)        
        painter.drawRect(300, self.height()-12, 3, 3)               
        
        self.d -= 1
        if self.d < -400:
            self.d = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 600)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**NLO.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все отлично, только картинка не выводится, лежит рядом с файлов питона